# Transferring steam items/skins between users

Tags: web, paypal, steam, steam-web-api, webshop

I'm developing CS:GO skins web shop, where you can trade your CS:GO skins. I want to use real money, not Steam.

That's how it should work:

1. User chooses skin to sell.
2. Sets skin price and submits.
3. Skin is removed from user inventory and transferred to another steam account(temporary inventory - here will be transferred every skin, it's like shop warehouse).
4. If another user is trying to buy skin, he must make a payment in paypal or other service, if payment was successfully, skin from temporary inventory transferred to user inventory.

I want to know if this is possible at all. If it is, how I can transfer items from one account to another?

Comment: I once build something simular, so yes, it's possible, but this isn't really a proper question. It's too broad for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Have you checked the steam api?

https://steamcommunity.com/dev

and then you can use Steambot for handling trade offers

https://github.com/Jessecar96/SteamBot

Answer (score 0):

This is called escrow servicing, and the Datk Net drug forums have done this with Bitcoin because it works for every service type across exchange rates and taxes.